# Windows 7 taking too much time for shutting down?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, shutdown

I have a PC with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 installed in it. My PC has a Pentium dual core processor and 2 GB RAM.

Both OS are working without any problems. But when it comes to the case of shut down, Windows takes more than 2 minutes to shut down, where Ubuntu takes a maximum of 20 seconds. Why this happens so ? How can I reduce the time of shut down in Windows ?

Comment: trace the shutdown with xbootmgr and give me the ETL file: http://pastebin.com/RFRkuc81

Comment: @magicandre1981 From the link you gave I found Windows SDK for Windows 8.1. Does it work on Windows 7, or is there a specific version for Windows 7 ?

Comment: the SDK/WPT also works on Windows 7.

Comment: How old is your windows? 32/64 bit?

Comment: @NKN Its nearly 1 year old and its 64 bit OS.

Comment: You know that Microsoft Windows gets bulkier as it gets older. I suggest first try some Registery Mechanic tools, but highly unlikely it solves the problem. So I would install a fresh windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

- Open the registry and locate the key {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management}.
- Then change the value of 'ClearPageFile' at Shutdown to a 0 if the value is 1.

If the value is 1, it will take longer for your computer to shutdown. This fix cured it all for me.

Also this can be done to reduce shut down time:

- Locate HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Highlight.
- Double click on Highlight and change the value of 'WaitToKillServiceTimeout' to 1000.

Comment: Tom, that forum link (as of right now) has 2 popular answers and 119 other answers. Please indicate what you find useful here on superuser, in its entirety. Consider the situation if the linked forum entry is no longer available, will a SuperUser reader have enough information to fix the problem?

Comment: much better answer!